# R Shiny DT data table column width works on ALL columns, but not on specific column

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have looked at the documentation, and examples, and other answers. But, for the life of me, I can't get the `DT::datatable()` to widen just one column in my output. When I set the option to include `_all` columns, it works, but obviously not what I want.

Here is a working example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

mtcars <- mtcars[1:5, ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput(('mtcarsDT')),
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtcarsDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
    recFeedbackCol <- lapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(recnum)
      as.character(
        radioButtons(
          paste0(
            'rec', recnum),
          '',
          choices = c('good' = 'Good', 'bad' = 'Bad', 'neutral' = 'Neutral'),
          inline = TRUE
        )
      )
    )
    recFeedbackCol <- tibble(feedback = recFeedbackCol)
    
    mtcars <- bind_cols(
      mtcars,
      recFeedbackCol
      )
    
    mtcars %>%
      DT::datatable(
        escape = FALSE, selection = 'none',
        extensions = 'FixedColumns',
        options = list(
          paging = FALSE, pageLength = 10, ordering = FALSE,  scrollX = TRUE,
          fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
            ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '
            ),
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = 'feedback'))
          )
        )
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Changing `targets = '_all'` works. But, that widens all columns.

```
> packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘1.4.0’
> packageVersion('DT')
[1] ‘0.17’
```

Anything I am missing?

**Update:**

Now, I am using `ncol(mtcars)` and with some options, and the DT does not render at all. I get the columns, and zero rows in display:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

mtcars <- mtcars[1:5, ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    dataTableOutput(('mtcarsDT')),
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mtcarsDT <- DT::renderDataTable({
    recFeedbackCol <- lapply(1:nrow(mtcars), function(recnum)
      as.character(
        radioButtons(
          paste0(
            'rec', recnum),
          '',
          choices = c('good' = 'Good', 'bad' = 'Bad', 'neutral' = 'Neutral'),
          inline = TRUE
        )
      )
    )
    recFeedbackCol <- tibble(feedback = recFeedbackCol)
    
    mtcars <- bind_cols(
      mtcars,
      recFeedbackCol
      )
    
    mtcars %>%
      DT::datatable(
        extensions = 'FixedColumns',
        rownames = FALSE,
        escape = FALSE,
        class="compact cell-border",
        options = list(
          pageLength = 15, 
          lengthChange = FALSE, 
          scrollX = TRUE,
          searching = FALSE,
          dom = 't',
          ordering = TRUE,
          fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 2),
          preDrawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'
          ),
          drawCallback = JS(
            'function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } '
          ),
          autoWidth = TRUE,
          columnDefs = list(
            list(width = '200px', targets = ncol(mtcars))
          )
        )
      )
    })
  }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `targets` you can use a column index number (indexing is zero-based):

```
targets = 3
```

Or to target multiple specific columns, use an array:

```
targets = list(3,4)
```

There are some additional options, too - see [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) for reference.

---

**Update**

So, using the fact mentioned above about indexing being zero-based, and looking at the reference documentation (see the above link), we can say the following:

- The first column in the table has an index of 0.
- The second column in the table has an index of 1.
- ... and so on.

And we can also say:

- The last column in the table has an index of -1.
- The second-to-last column in the table has an index of -2.
- ... and so on.

Comment: See above update, and there new code that gives a problem.

Comment: OK - if you changed other parts of your table & app, I think that is now a new/different question about a new/different problem. If you go back to the original, does it work with my suggested syntax?

Comment: Yes. Although, I want a robust solution that works with the addition of just a basic set of options. The target field seems to have some problem playing well.

Comment: OK - I recommend you go ahead and ask that as a new question, making it clear what the specific issue is. I will keep an eye out for that new question. Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thank you. dOK. I can. Although, if you know the answer, not clear why you won't help further? I mean, the system asks for minimal reproducible example, which I posted. Then, a new problem crept up. Of course, if you don't know the solution to this new problem, I will gladly post as a new question. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to help - but I am having a hard time understanding what the new problem is (or the new set of problems are). A new question would be great. That's why I said "_making it clear what the specific issue is._". Also, I think doing that would really be to your advantage: You are _much_ more likely to get _many_ more eyeballs on your new problem if you present it in a new question (at least, that is what my experience has been). And you are probably going to get someone who can therefore provide the best possible answer - and that person may not be me!